# Cannot install Home-brew, Failed to connect to 50.63.202.24 port 443

Tags: ruby, xcode, homebrew

My attempts to update a pod fail because Cocoapod cannot connect to   50.63.202.24 port 443.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Failed to connect to 50.63.202.24 port 443: Operation timed out
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force

I've seen many posts on this problem and unfortunately, the solutions often require access to git master which also fails. I'm not using any proxy and the firewall on my Mac is turned off. Pod updates used to function without a problem for me up until a few months ago.

All the attempts I've made to solve this problem based on suggestions I've seen on the net usually require a similar access attempt which fails as above. As far as I can tell nothing is blocked on my Mac so I don't know where the breakdown is.  Can anyone suggest something to check? As I noted, I used to be able to do Github pod updates without a problem and now nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed when I removed Homebrew directory and installed again brew:

1. `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`
2. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. `brew update`
4. `brew doctor`